# Selecting images inside of images

Tags: python, opencv

I have [this image and](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vid7y.jpg) I want to select all the maps in it including the names using python.

I have tried it using OpenCv

```
from cv2 import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

for image in os.listdir('assets'):
    print(image)
    img_rgb = cv2.imread(image)
    template = cv2.imread('assets/template/template.png')
    w, h = template.shape[:-1]
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_rgb, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    threshold = .8
    loc = np.where(res >= threshold)
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):  # Switch columns and rows
        cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

    cv2.imwrite('result.png', img_rgb)
    break
```

But I always get this error:

> OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:1104: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function 'cv::matchTemplate

How do I do it? Please help

Comment: Can you show the full traceback? I’m not sure which `cv2` call in the for-loop throws this error

Comment: did you get it to work? what was the error

Answer (score 1):

`cv2.matchTemplate` will return this error when one of it's arguments is `NoneType`. In other words, `img_rgb` is nothing, most likely because no image was found at that location.

Here's how I reproduced your error:

```
from cv2 import cv2
import numpy as np

img_rgb = cv2.imread('fjdlfkjdlkfjdlfksdad')  # or None
template = np.random.randint(0, 256, (100, 100, 3))
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_rgb, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
```

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-
>       python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\templmatch.cpp:1104: error: (-215:Assertion failed) 
>       (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in 
>       function 'cv::matchTemplate'

Comment: No, the image was found for sure

Comment: i think you forgot to add `'assets/'` to files found inside folder `'assets'` to read them. `img_rgb = cv2.imread('assets/' + image)`